# Given a compact set $K$ and closed set $E,$ prove: $E\cap K\neq \emptyset $

Tags: general-topology

> Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set and $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ a closed set, such that:
>
> $$\inf\{d(x,y):x\in K, y\in E\}=0$$
>
> where $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_j(x_j-y_j)^2}$
>
> **Prove:** $E\cap K\neq \emptyset $

I tried to work with the definitions of compact and closed sets, and I understand that from what's given of the distance between elements in $K$ and $E$, that they are very close,  but couldn't really get further.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, take $e_n\in E$ and $k_n\in K$ such that $d(e_n,k_n)<\frac1n$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a subsequence $k_{m_n}$ of the sequence $(k_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which converges to some $k\in K$. But then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e_{m_n}=k$ and, since $E$ is closed, $k\in E$. Therefore $k\in E\cap K$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\lim_{n \to \infty} e_n = k?$

Comment: @Itay4 That's because $d(e_{m_n},k)\leqslant d(e_{m_n},k_{m_n})+d(k_{m_n},k)<\frac1{m_n}+d(k_{m_n},k)$.

Answer (score 2):

$f:K \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)  = d(x,E) = \inf \{d(x,y): y \in E\}$ is continuous on $K$.
$f$ must assume a minimum at some $k \in K$. By the assumption $f(k) = 0 =d(k,E)$ must hold (the function is $\ge0$ and we can always get below any $r>0$). But for closed $E$: $d(k,E)=0$ implies $k \in E$. So this is our common point for $E$ and $K$.